# Assigning random coordinates to obstacles in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, ios, random, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I'm trying to create a set of randomly placed obstacles. To do this, I need to draw an instance of a random x variable, and a random y variable, and then set its position to that x and that y variable. To pick the variables, I use the following code:

```
srand(time(0));

int i = rand()%4;
int j = rand()%3;

float x = .125+i*.25;
float y = .167+j*.33;
```

It may look funky at first glance, but it creates x as one of the four numbers I want, and y as one of the three numbers I want. I've run this code, and when I debug it, in Xcode, it tells me x equals NaN, and y also equal NaN. I know this means Not-A-Number, but I'm not sure why this happens, because I tested it in a command line tool application like so:

```
srand(time(0));
for (int n = 0; n<10; n++) {
    int i = rand()%4;
    int j = rand()%3;

    float x = .125+i*.25;
    float y = .167+j*.33;

    cout << x << "," << y << endl;
}
```

This gave me exactly what I expected, a set of random coordinates:

```
    0.625,0.497
    0.125,0.497
    0.875,0.827
    0.375,0.497
    0.875,0.167
    0.625,0.497
    0.875,0.827
    0.875,0.827
    0.125,0.167
    0.625,0.827
```

Why is this? I've used this code in a command line tool to test it out, seen that it works, and  then tried to put it to use in the context of the game, and the debugger returns NaN. What am I missing in the game that I have in the command line?

Comment: which cocos2dx version are you using?

Comment: Cocos2dx version 2.2.2

Comment: potshot: you're calculating with mixed integer and double values, but end up assigning the result to float, possibly truncating the values. Try: double x = .125 + (double)i * .25;